# Adding cluster to existing elastic search in elk

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Currently I have existing

```
1. Elastic search
2. Logstash
3. Kibana
```

I have existing data on them.

Now i have setup ELK cluster with 3 Master nodes , 5 data nodes 3 client nodes.

But i am not sure how can i get existing data into them.

Is it possible that if i make the existing ES node as data node and then attach it to the cluster . Then will that data gets replicated to other data nodes as well? and then take that node offline

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

How about just try with fewer nodes? It is not hard to test if it is supported if you setup one node, feed some data, and add one more and configure them as a cluster to see if data get synchronized.

**Option 2**

Another option is to use an elasticsearch migration tool like https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump, basically, you could setup a clean cluster and migrate all your data in old node to this cluster.